# List of small rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

Where can I find a list of small rings? (like the one [Wikipedia has for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups))

(obviously I  don't expect it to be as comprehensive given how many rings there can be for certain orders, but if there's a list out there that at least covers a fair few of the easier sizes of a ring to deal with, that'd be great)

Comment: What you need, Ass, is https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The English Wikipedia aritcle [Finite ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_ring) has some good pointers to information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170501203914/http://home.wlu.edu/~dresdeng/smallrings/) interesting, it has some details about `small rings'.  Also for enumeration there is a sequence on the OEIS:

https://oeis.org/A037234

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the paper Rings of Small Order by Fletcher, or [these notes](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2200/v15/smallrings.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

The Database of Ring Theory is very elegantly put together.  Is this what you need?

[Rings by cardinality](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/dimensions/?dimension_type=3)

Comment: This is a very cool site but the page you linked to seems to deal mostly with infinite rings. Is there a page on DaRT where you can see lists of (small) finite groups (possibly ordered by cardinality)? (I'm sorry I'm not very savvy with stuff like this)

Comment: Ass, yes, probably.  You have to try out their search features.  I'm not studying rings right now (probability theory right now myself :)))

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 I would just recommend you use the search feature and specify “finite”. That [gets you these results](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=43). Unfortunately it is not meant to be an exhaustive list of small rings. Th database strives to store rings which display a wide variety of properties.